# Can I update my binary when it's waiting for review without being thrown back in the waiting queue?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I've submitted an app a few days ago and it's still waiting for review. In the meantime I've done some improvements... could I submit that new binary now or is that going to reset my waiting time so that I basically start from scratch again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must reject your binary that is in review before updating it. This will, in turn, place you in the back of the queue, as stated on Apple's Developer website.

Comment: well but it's not in review, it's waiting for review ... or do you mean the same thing?

Comment: If you modify the binary at any time, either In Review or Waiting for Review, you get pushed back in the queue.

Comment: @EvanMulawski Is it possible to update the app version, even if your app is "Waiting for Review". i.e Binary V1.1 show waiting for review, but want to add new version 1.2. I don't think "Reject this Binary" will work in my case. Any help from you ?

Comment: @AjaySharma: Creating a new version while your previous version is in review is not possible. This is because there is always the possibility that the version in review can be rejected (resulting in the current version remaining Ready For Sale and the update now Rejected). In other words, no, because you can't build up a queue of new versions. If you could, hypothetically, if one version in the queue gets rejected, the rest will have to be rejected immediately.

Comment: @EvanMulawski Thats perfect, & sounds promising.But good news is that app got approved yesterday eve. And uploaded new version ;) Thanks!!!!